# Linq statement to iterate through a collection and making sure each item is in the correct order?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-objects

i'm got a simple `IEnumerable<foo> foos;` This collection are some results from a db call.

I wish to make sure that each item in the list is ordered correctly. The Db either returns the results by

- ordered by id, lowest to highest. eg. 1, 2, 3, 4,. ... etc.
- ordered by date created, decrement (most recent, first).

Can this be done with a quick linq statement .. to check for this?

eg. `Assert.IsTrue(.. insert linq statement here .. )`

currently, i've got a for loop and remember the previous entry and check if the value of that, if there was a value. This feels ... cumbersome.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could compare your collection to an ordered version:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(foos.ToList(), foos.OrderBy(f => f.Id));
```

Or:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(foos.ToList(), 
                          foos.OrderByDescending(f => f.DateCreated));
```

Comment: @Andy White , wow - that is very interesting! I never knew there was a CollectionAssert class :) that's awesome! That said, When I tried to do your code, i didn't have to do a ToList() for the first parameter ... but for the second one i DID have to add a .ToList() to the end of that funct .. can you just confirm that, please?

Comment: Oh, whoops, IEnumerable doesn't have a ToList() method.  There are a few different techniques to convert an IEnumerable to a List.  You might be able to apply a no-op extension method call to get it into a format that can be converted to a List.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension method called [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) which will do that. However, there is also an assert method called [CollectionAssert.AreEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243763(VS.80).aspx) that compares two collections to ensure they have the same items in the same order.