# How to use CollectionAssert (and Linq?) to find all the values for one property, are the same?

Tags: .net, linq, mstest, icollection

this is an extension to a [previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189812/linq-statement-to-iterate-through-a-collection-and-making-sure-each-item-is-in-th), today .... which highlighted the use of CollectionAssert to help test collections (which I never knew).

I have an `ICollection<Foo> foos;` This has a property called Status, which .. to keep things simple, is an int or byte (whatever floats your boat <-- see what I did there?! /me hides).

So, how can I use CollectionAssert to see if all the items, in the returned ICollection, all have the same value for that one property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything in `CollectionAssert` to help, but you could do something like:

```
int expectedValue = foos.First().Status;
Assert.IsTrue(foos.All(x => x.Status == expectedValue));
```

It's not ideal in that it won't show you the actual values in case of failure - but you could write your own method for that, if you need to do this regularly.

Comment: Thanks Jon (again :P). this is great. I constantly forget about the ~All(..)~ extension method. This will work like a treat :)